Space fantasy book involving a man searching for a replacement planet for Earth and an alien girl from a faraway world who can astral project
I'm looking for a book I read In 2006/2007. I don't know the author's name and can't remember the book title. But here's a brief synopsis of the story that I can recollect.
The story is told from the point of view of two characters; one male, one female. The male's story consists of being on an arc. He is looking for a replacement planet for Earth and is going to be sent into cryosleep when he runs into an astral projection of a little girl who is from an alien world far away from Earth. The young man is put into cryosleep and the story then takes place from the perspective of the little girl.
The little girl lives on a planet full of priests who has the village astral project. She is trained to harness and use her powers for five years and then is introduced to a helper so she'll have to go on some quest. The details are bit foggy from there.
The last thing I remember is that the human spaceship was set to arrive on her planet but is instead diverted from her planet and sets course for a more barren planet. Which is the same planet she ends up on for the last phase of persuasion.
That's all I remember from when I read this book. Anyone have any hints?  Would much appreciate a title, or even the author's name would be wonderful.

Hi, welcome to the site. I made fairly extensive edits to your description in an attempt to improve the formatting and grammar. If any of the changes I made don't accurately reflect what you meant, please edit the question yourself to fix it. :-)

By the way, you added the [alien-invasion] tag to the question, but I didn't see any mention of that in your description. How does an alien invasion factor into the story, if at all?
